# Onepage dropdown sidebar - active based on position of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there way how to do smoothscroll to the section and dropdown the nav section where is current position of page without clicking by mouse? And if the div is not active then dropup the section1?

[image: Active home, because position of page is on section Home]

[image: Dropdown section 1 - active div 1, because position of page is on div1]

Comment: use scrollspyjs.. https://github.com/makotot/scrollspy

Comment: https://codepen.io/makotot/pen/YyRXOQ

Comment: Yes this is good, but is possible to do, when is page on section 1-div1 the sidebar menu dropdown just section 1 and made active div1 (the same for section2 etc.)? And one question, how to do smoothscoll to the section/div? I want exactly same like here https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html Thanks

Comment: try adding active class to the dropdowns when any section inside is that dropdown is active

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by tocify javascript. http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/